# Intercept incoming emails via Dovecot

Tags: centos, dovecot

I'm looking for a way to intercept emails received via a dovecot server. Our intent is to somehow capture the header and body of the email, store it in the database (as useable data) which we can process at a later stage.

We're attempting to setup a backup mail server so that when our's goes down, it will capture all emails received and via a cronjob resend these emails to the recipient.

Where would I start? We're happy to use Postfix or any other existing platform to achieve something similiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail-server failover has a simple approved solution.

Add low-priority MX record to your DNS-zone:

```
IN MX 10 mail.domain.tld
IN MX 20 fo.mail.domain.tld
```

While everything is Ok, messages are passed to the `mail.domain.tld`. If it went out, messages are passed to the failover MTA `fo.mail.domain.tld`. Here MTA is configured to use `smarthost` (that is `mail.domain.tld`) and while primary server is offline messages are stored in the queue. When primary server wake up, secondary server push all the delayed messages to it.

Comment: If I did one thing right today it was to ask a professional :) Thank you! If I were to still want to get the sender/receiver information for each email coming in, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, any half-decent MTA will log this as mail enters and leaves queue.